# RegEx for 1-6 digits followed by .nn

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using JavaScript and would be grateful for a pattern that matches 1 through 6 digits followed by an optional `.nn`.

So, in the end I'd like to have a function that returns True for strings that match the patterns like these:

```
nn
nnn
nn.nn
nnnnn.nn
nnnn
nnnnnn.nn
nnnnnn
```

(where `n` is a digit).

Thanks!!

Comment: Are all the `n`s in your example supposed to represent numeric digits?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `/^\d{1,6}(.\d\d)?$/`  so the js would look like:

```
/^\d{1,6}(\.\d\d)?$/.test(str)
```

Comment: thanks!! does the ? make the .nn optional? How would you do it if the .nn was required. Thanks!!

Comment: I think his ".nn" meant two decimal digits, not a literal `.nn`.

Comment: Just remove ? if you want it to be required

Comment: Thanks for your help but this will return True for strings like 77. and 125. and if there is a decimal point the 2 digits to the right should be required.

Comment: @user I am confused at what you say because it won't pass for 77. are you sure you are looking at the right thing? .xx is optional

Comment: @user815460 - Have you tested it? It should return False for those strings, unless I'm very much mistaken. The parentheses around the last part should ensure that.

Answer (score 2):

The following will work:

```
^[0-9]{1,6}(\.[0-9][0-9])?$
```

You could use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` in modern regex engines, I'm just allowing for the lowest common denominator). In other words, this is equivalent to:

```
^\d{1,6}(\.\d\d)?$
```

The `{1,6}` bit is how you specify that the previous match is to occur 1 thru 6 times inclusive, and the `X?` is the same as `X{0,1}` (in other words, `(\.[0-9][0-9])?` means that the period followed by exactly two digits can occur exactly zero or one time).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the helpful explanation, but this will return True for strings like 77. and 125. and if there is a decimal point the 2 digits to the right should be required

Comment: @user815460, no it won't. The parentheses treat the `.nn` as an atomic unit - either the whole thing has to be there or none of it is allowed. You can test it at http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm

Answer (score 2):

try this regex:

```
/\d{1,6}(?:\.\d\d)?/
```

#### EDIT:

Based on comments from @Justin here is the enhanced reges:

```
/(?:^|\b)\d{1,6}(?:\.\d\d)?(?:\b|$)/
```

To make sure only this number is matched separated by word boundaries.

Comment: This won't filter out numbers longer than 7 digits or decimals longer than 2 digits; I suggest wrapping it in `\b` symbols or `^` / `$` to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: `\w{1,6}(\.nn){0,1}`

You say digits, but show nnnn.nn. The above is for the example nnnn.nn, but you can change for numerical digits easily by:

```
\d{1,6}(\.nn){0,1}
```